# Link in email malformed

Tags: c#, email, html-email, sendgrid

I'm using a zero pixel image with the image src being used to track emails opened metric. The issue is my URL originally looks like this,

/bf0e615f-a9cb-42b8-a9fe-db77c7fc697d?type=emailRead&id=1

But I'm getting exceptions from my server logs where the URL looks like this (notice the = in between the string),

/bf0e615f-a9cb-42b8-a9fe-db77c7fc697d?type=em=ailRead&id=1

This is not a one-off incident and we're seeing this regularly. We use sendgrid API for sending email using c#, if that helps.
TIA.